# Execute Import / Load db2 command from PHP code

Tags: php, import, db2, load

I am new to db2. I want to execute import command from my php code but I get following error. I have checked my db2 connection also it is working but command is not getting executed.

Command I used:

```
$output="IMPORT FROM receipt_master.del OF DEL INSERT INTO RECEIPT_MASTER (FIN_YEAR , TREA_CODE , MN_YY , MAJOR_HEAD , TRAN_ID , DATE , CHALLAN_NO)";
```

Error I am getting:

```
Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]:
SQL error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] 
SQL0104N An unexpected token "receipt_master.del" was found following "IMPORT FROM ".
Expected tokens may include: "JOIN". SQLSTATE=42601 , SQL state 42601 in SQLExecDirect
```

Answer (score 1):

`IMPORT` is not a regular SQL statement and hence cannot be executed the way you are attempting it. You could look into calling the [ADMIN_CMD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0012547.html) procedure. Basically, you would call a procedure from your code. That procedure would then execute the IMPORT command on your behalf. There is an entire section on using [IMPORT within the ADMIN_CMD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023575.html).

Comment: If you want to use `IMPORT` or `LOAD` then you have to execute them via the `ADMIN_CMD` stored procedure.